# Groupconcat using mysql select

Tags: mysql, sql

I am trying to create groupconcat in my sql query.The following is my data in the table, but not getting the expected result.

Table:users

```
 id    name     groupflag
 ------------------------------ 
 1     san1     0  
 2     san2     0  
 3     san3     277  
 4     san4     277  
 5     san5     277  
 6     san6     288  
 7     san7     288
```

I need the result in the following format, need to groupconcat the name field having groupflag not equal to 0,
The name field should group by comma based on the groupflag value

```
id    name             groupflag
-------------------------------------------
1     san1             0
2     san2             0
3     san3,san4,san5   277
6     san5,san6        288
```

This is my query:

```
  SELECT IF(users.groupflag <> 0 ,GROUP_CONCAT(users.name SEPARATOR ','),'') 
  AS name     FROM users 
  GROUP BY groupflag
```

Answer (score 4):

You can use [`UNION`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/union.html) to combine two separate queries:

```
SELECT   name, groupflag
FROM     users
WHERE    groupflag = 0

UNION ALL

SELECT   GROUP_CONCAT(name), groupflag
FROM     users
WHERE    groupflag <> 0
GROUP BY groupflag
```

See it on [sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/d4608/1/0).

Answer (score 0):

```
select id, group_concat(`Name` separator ',') as `Column`
from
(
select id, concat(`Name`, ':',
group_concat(`Value` separator ',')) as `Name`
from mytbl
group by id, `Name`
) tbl
group by groupflag;
```